# Should root certificates have OCSP or CRL for it?

Tags: tls, certificates, ocsp, root, crl

Should root certificates have OCSP or CRL for its own revocation status?

So here is what I mean:

```
Intermediate Cert -> http://example.com/root.crl
SAN Cert -> https://example.com/intermediate.crl
```

But should you create a crl database for root?

```
Root Cert -> http://example.com/root.crl
```

Like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, root CA never includes CDP and AIA extensions in their CA certificate, because it provides zero value. Most revocation checking tools skip root CA certificate checking, because root CA revocation is an undefined operation.

Comment: That is interesting.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that though? I want to make sure before I generate that root cert.